# How to call Java class from other file in Visual Studio Codes

Tags: java, class, visual-studio-code

For example: 
I have in VS Code two Java classes in two different files.

File X.java

```
package PackageName;
public class X
{
   public static main(String[] args)
   {
      //What I want to do
      var x = new Y("Hello World!")
   }
}
```

File Y.java

```
package PackageName;
public class Y
{

   public Y(Object parameter)
   {
      var x = parameter;
   }
}
```

I cant get access class Y. I tried `package PackageName;` on top of both files but a error shows: Package name "" expected (The declared package "PackageName" does not match the expected package "" [536871240]).

When I write both classes in one file it works. but it would be good if I could use two different files.

Comment: show the code that you have tried with the package declaration.

Comment: I added package PackageName; But VS Code sais It need to be ""

Comment: Can you also post the actual error

Comment: The error: The declared package "PackageName" does not match the expected package "" [536871240]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, probably your source file is in the top level src directory, but as it is in a `package` it should be in a sub-directory called `PackageName`

Comment: I does not have any directories. Both files are in same one and only folder.

Comment: You will have to create the sub-folder

Comment: you mean creating a src folder?

Comment: No, as per my answer it should be in a sub-directory called PackageName

Comment: @ScaryWombat, but may I know why I have to create a sub-folder for it?

Comment: @ikhvjs Because that is how it works!

Answer (score 0):

Add your .java files into a same folder then go to File --> Add folder to workspace then select your folder and its should work now

Answer (score 0):

compile your entire src folder command line if all your java files are in same folder without any package.
Navigate to your src directory and run the command javac *.java.

It should work.